# JSON.parse и перенос строки SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

```
 console.log($scope.editedJson);
 $scope.editedJson=JSON.parse($scope.editedJson);
 console.log($scope.editedJson);
```

Первый консоль лог:

```
{"operation":"addtask","etalon":"int res=z+y;
1","lang":"c++","task":"123","function":{"function_name":"sum","type":0,"array_type":0,"size":null,"unit_test_num":1,"checkable_args_indexes":[[{"first":0,"second":0}]],"results":[],"compare_mark":[0],"tests_code":[""],"args":[{"type":0,"size":null,"arg_name":"x","pattern":{},"value":["1"],"is_array":0,"etalon_value":[""],"compare_mark":[0]},{"type":0,"size":null,"arg_name":"y","pattern":{},"value":["2"],"is_array":0,"etalon_value":[""],"compare_mark":[0]}]}}
```

Второй:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
$scope.editedJson=JSON.parse($scope.editedJson);
```

Проблема кажется в переносе строки после `int res=z+y;` Пробовал вот так

```
$scope.editedJson=JSON.parse($scope.editedJson.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n"));
```

не помогло

Синтаксис AngularJS, но это думаю не важно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Валидный JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) не должен иметь спецсимволов. Все они должны быть экранированы.

Вы правильно поняли, что не парсится перевод строки, но неправильно экранируете его (лишний раз экранируете `\n` в регулярном выражении). Нужно так:

```
$scope.editedJson=JSON.parse($scope.editedJson.replace(/\n/g, "\\n"));
```